# "No module named balanced_django.middleware"

Tags: django, balanced-payments

I get the following error when I try to install 
https://github.com/balanced/balanced-django
 "No module named balanced_django.middleware"

I followed the instructions provided in the README file.

```
1. pip install balanced
```

(after doing source env/bin/activate,
   I ran pip install backend)

```
2. MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += (
    ...
    'balanced_django.middleware.BalancedMiddleware',
    ...
)

3. BALANCED = {
    'secret': '7b7a51ccb10c11e19c0a026ba7e239a9',
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On the git of the project I don’t see any balanced_django module. Try with balanced-django or maybe balancedex instead of balanced_django.

Comment: Yeah, Andrew is right. Balanced-Django is just a demo on how to use Django with Balanced. What you want is django-balanced.

Comment: Also, try this: https://github.com/balanced/django-example/

Answer (score 2):

It looks like 'balanced-django' isn't actually a library, but rather an old demo of how to integrate Django with Balanced.

I've found what looks to be the library you want (and appears to be actively developed):

https://github.com/balanced/django-balanced